# Performing a variable based sqlite3 update through php

Tags: php, sqlite

I am attempting to perform an update to a Sqlite3 database through a PHP script, but I am running into a pair of errors that I do not understand.

> PHP Warning:  SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such column: :column in C:\UwAmp\www\save.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/Canvas.html
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function `bindParam()` on boolean in C:\UwAmp\www\save.php:17\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in C:\UwAmp\www\save.php on line 17, referer: http://localhost/Canvas.html

Here is an example of the PHP code I am using:

```
$url = $_POST['newURL'];
$name = $_POST['saveName'];
$index = $_POST['saveNum'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$db = new SQLite3('Users.db');



$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE Canvas_Saves SET ':column' = ':url' WHERE User = ':user'");
$statement->bindParam(':url', $url);
$statement->bindParam(':user', $user);
if($index ===1){
    $statement->bindParam(':column', 'Save1',SQLITE3_TEXT);
}
else if($index ===2){
    $statement->bindParam(':column', 'Save2',SQLITE3_TEXT);
}
else if($index ===3){
    $statement->bindParam(':column', 'Save3',SQLITE3_TEXT);
}
else if($index ===4){
    $statement->bindParam(':column', 'Save4',SQLITE3_TEXT);
}

$statement->execute();
```

Line 16 is the $db->prepare statement.
I have attempted to research this, but I have not had any luck. Thank you for any help you may be able to give.

Comment: How is the table structure?

Comment: The relevant fields are Save1, Save2, Save3, Save4 in table Canvas_Saves. Each of the fields are TEXT type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
$url = $_POST['newURL'];
$name = $_POST['saveName'];
$index = $_POST['saveNum'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$db = new SQLite3('Users.db');
$col="";
if($index ===1){
    $col="Save1";
}
else if($index ===2){
    $col="Save2";
}
else if($index ===3){
    $col="Save3";
}
else if($index ===4){
    $col="Save4";
}
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE Canvas_Saves SET ".$col."=:url  WHERE User = :user ");
$statement->bindParam(":url", $url);
$statement->bindParam(":user", $user);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: This leaves me with this error. 


`PHP Warning:  SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near &quot;=&quot;: syntax error in C:\\UwAmp\\www\\save.php on line 26, referer: http://localhost/Canvas.html`

Line 26 refers to the prepare statement.

Comment: I believe that I had an issue with my index that I was passing in. Thank you for your help.